# vbscript shell using START command fails, OK from command line

Tags: shell, vbscript, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to loop through a long list of folders and use the command line option of 7-zip (7z.exe) to create a ZIP archive of each folder, so I'm using VBScript.  Using the START command as shown in the code and comments result in the

> <>.vbs(28, 2) (null): The system cannot find the file specified

error regardless of whether output redirection is used (>>).

If I run the exact value of strCommandLine from the command prompt it works fine.

I need to use the .run method since that's the only way I could see to invoke 7z.exe and wait for it to complete before running the next one.  Also, since each call to 7z takes about an hour to run (and uses substantial system resources), I'd like to run it at IDLE priority (the /LOW switch).

In the code sample I've included, I've tried 3 different methods (and they are commented as to what happens with each).  I need that last method (using the Windows Start command) to work, since it's the only way I know to accomplish running at IDLE priority.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("E:\Documents\MJW")
Set colFolders = objFolder.SubFolders
Set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Const strPath = "E:\test\"
Const strParam = "-mx 3"
Const str7ZipCmd = """C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe"""
' will use start /low to invoke 7-zip\7z
'On Error Resume Next

idx = 0

For Each objFolder in colFolders
  strFolderName = objFolder.Name
  strFileName = strFolderName & ".zip"
  Wscript.Echo idx, strFileName
  If objFSO.FileExists(strPath & strFileName) Then
    Wscript.Echo idx," file exists: ", strFileName
  Else
' cannot redirect output or set IDLE priority with this, but it works
'   strCommandLine = str7ZipCmd & " a " & strPath&strFileName & " .\" & strFolderName & "\* -mx=3"
' same here
'   strCommandLine = "CMD /C " & str7ZipCmd & " a " & strPath & strFileName & " .\" & strFolderName & "\* -mx=3 >> C2Backup.log"
' this is the one I'm trying to get working
    strCommandLine = "START """" /B /LOW /WAIT " & str7ZipCmd & " a " & strPath & strFileName & " .\" & strFolderName & "\* -mx=3 >> C2Backup.log"
' this results in "E:\Documents\MJW\listfolders3.vbs(28, 2) (null): The system cannot find the file specified" error whether or not the redirect >> is included
' if I execute the same resulting START command at the command prompt even with redirect, it works fine ??!!
    intReturn = oShell.Run(strCommandLine, 1, true)     'this is the line that generates the error, no value for shReturn is returned
    Wscript.Echo "Executed " & strCommandLine, intReturn
  End If
  idx = idx + 1
Next
```

Comment: my guess would be that the problem is with the .\ Foldername you use. The run will use the directory of the script as the working directory. To change this you can use oShell.CurrentDirectory. However imo it is preferable in a script like this to get rid of the relativ paths anyway and just use the full path in the call

Comment: I tried specifying the full path both as source and destination path, but still got the same error.  Here's the program output:

Comment: Forced to create another comment - only allowed 5 min to edit comment (?!)...I removed the output redirection >>.  Here's a sample of the program output:  4 Process.zip
Executed START "" /B /LOW /WAIT "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" a E:\test\Process.zip E:\Documents\MJW\Process\* -mx=3

Comment: Well the start thing can't work because it is an internal cmd command not an exe so it cannot be called directly (cmd /c START would work but it only adds unnecessary complexion to your troubleshooting imo) the first example you have with the "str7ZipCmd & " a " & strPath&strFileName ... " should work just fine though.

Comment: I had documented that in the code (using str7ZipCmd & ...) - it does work, but can't redirect output nor set IDLE priority.  I also had tried "cmd/c START and that had failed the same way.  I think I'll end up using the code to generate a bunch of individual START statements, then put them in a batch file and try that.

Comment: Correction - I had tried "cmd/c START ..." but was using relative paths, but had not tested cmd/c START... with absolute paths.  THAT WORKED, including output redirection and all the other START options (such as IDLE priority).  Thanks for your help! :-)